# How can I declare a variable outside of a block when the variable defines an anonymous class in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code and it works good:

```
var _data = (from qu in _que.GetAll(
  u => u.company == "GE" )
  select new {
    qu.name,
    qu.address
});
```

The signature of the GetALL method is

```
ICollection<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

Now I need to enclose the above in some block so it becomes:

```
{
    var _data = (from qu in _que.GetAll(
      u => u.company == "GE" )
      select new {
        qu.name,
        qu.address
    });
}
var _abc = _data; <<< doesn't work now
```

Once I do this then _data becomes local and I can't access it from outside the block. I assume that what I need to do is to declare _data outside of the block. But what do I declare it too as they type that's returned and placed into _data is an anonymous type. Is there some way I can declare _data without having to change the query or make up some return type?

Comment: Since `var` is a compile-time construct, I cant see why it shouldn't be possible to declare `var _data` just outside such a scope and assign within it.  There would be potential for errors if user tried to assign different objects conditionally, but that can be checked for or warned.  The type of `var` could still be inferred from any of the first potential assignments.  Anyone agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I *think* I understand it, just about. Personally I try to avoid requiring this, but you *can* do something like:

```
// I'm assuming name and address are strings
var _data = Enumerable.Repeat(new { name = "", address = "" }, 0);
_data = null; // Never actually want to use that value

if (someCondition)
{
    _data = from qu in _que.GetAll(u => u.company == "GE")
            select new { qu.name, qu.address };
}
```

So long as you use the same property names and types, the two anonymous types here will be equivalent, so you can perform the second assignment with no problems. Note that I've changed the formatting of your query expression - I believe this looks *much* clearer, as previously it looked like the `GetAll` argument was part of the query expression itself.

Given that your query expression is just a single select, I'd probably actually just write:

```
_data = _que.GetAll(u => u.company == "GE")
            .Select(qu => new { qu.name, qu.address });
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Your answer looks great although I was hoping there would be some really easy way that would not require me to kind of make another class that looks like the anonymous class. Thank you also for the rewrite tips.

Comment: Jon@ - Would it be possible for me to declare a class for this select , then write "select new ClassABC { ... " etc.  If I did this then would that make it easier to declare the variable _data?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, that would be an alternative. I've also asked for the feature of a "named anonymous class" (give me an immutable class with appropriate properties, equality etc). Maybe one day :)

Answer (score 0):

With Resharper at least, and if you don't mind losing the `var`, you can quickly change it to the explicit type declaration, then move it to the outer scope.  Just a few clicks.  But agree with Marc and Jon, I come across this all too often and it's often messy.

Comment: Hello Kieren, I don't know about resharper. Can you explain what this would do for me? Certainly I don't mind losing the var. I just want something that works good.

Comment: It's a productivity/code refactoring/etc addin for Visual Studio.  It's not free though.  With it, you can put the cursor over `_data`, click the refactor icon, select 'Change to explicit type..' option, then do the same again but select 'Move to outer scope'. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Are there any other "free" tools that could do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with any :(

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the surrounding code, but you could delay the `Select` until after the block.

```
ICollection<SomeType> _data = null;
...
{
    _data = _que.GetAll(u => u.company == "GE");
}
...
var _abc = from qu in _data select new { qu.name, qu.address };
```